# Bootstrap 4 Beta 2 navbar-toggler not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm practicing Bootstrap and have added a navbar to my webpage. However neither the nav-bar toggler is working for small screens nor does the icon navbar-toggler-icon appears.

Here's my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>  
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>         
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have already searched on the internet and found that I may be misplacing the jquery but I have double checked and found that I have added javascript at the bottom of the body in the following order:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have also verified that the browser is fetching the javascript files as can be seen:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kvdnurrf/2/) to jsfiddle

EDIT2: I found the culprit, its the link . I don't know why it's not working since I have added it using npm and the dependencies in the package.json show it as below:

```
{
 "name": "confusion",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
 "main": "index.html",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "npm run lite",
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 "lite": "lite-server"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
 "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
 "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
 "jquery": "^3.2.1",
 "popper.js": "^1.12.6"
 }
 }
```

EDIT 3: The following error occurs in console regarding the popper:

[image]

Comment: can you add fiddle of it

Comment: I didn't get you. DO you mean copying the entire html into fiddle?

Comment: Added in the post.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, wondering how you resolved yours?

Comment: @AngelaPan I was in correctly linking the popper.js. You should link the node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js instead of node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the UMD release of Popper.js it's the only one which work on a browser : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.nav-inverse` and add `navbar-dark bg-dark` if you want to make it dark colored. You also need to add `data-toggle` attribute on `.navbar-toggle` button.

Here is a working example of the navbar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sezuzov/edit?html,output) of the above code.

Comment: That took care of the problem where navbar-toggler-icon was not appearing. However I tested it both in Firefox and Chrome and in its responsive tabs the button is still not working as a Toggler. It just appears. I have already added the data-toggle attribute as shown in my original post.

Secondly, how do I make the nav bar of the color of my choosing as I did in my original post now after switching to bg-dark and navbar-dark?

Comment: Id of your div containing `.navbar-nav` must match `data-target` on `.navbar-toggle` button, otherwise it won't work. Regarding navbar color, there are few color provided by bootstrap out of the box http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/, you can add additional color with css.

Comment: Thanks for that, however I still don't know why my popper.js link is not working. Do you have any idea? I have edited my original post.

Comment: Do you have any error on console? based on your screenshot it seems like it's loading properly. Try testing by loading bootstrap and other dependencies from cdn, You can find them on http://getbootstrap.com/ home page. Also make sure to load scripts before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is only with popper. It works when I load it from CDN but from my server it doesn't work. And you're right there's one error that pops up in the console. Screenshot attached in the OP.

Comment: Instead of loading `node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js` load `node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js` as it's shown on bootstrap home page, your issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NPM you don't need to include the scripts tags of each library into the HTML code. For example in Laravel, you only need to include `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` at the bottom inside the body.

Then you should check your package.json file to have at least:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"popper.js": "^1.14",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

Hope this helps, it worked for me.